# Two external function calls not working in combination in our smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, truffle-contract

So I have the following functions

**buyTokens**

```
function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public payable {
    require(beneficiary != address(0));
    require(validPurchase());

    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

    uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(getRate());

    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    token.issue(address(vault), tokens);
    vault.deposit.value(msg.value)(beneficiary, tokens);

    emit TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

    forwardFunds();
}
```

**forwardFunds**

```
function forwardFunds() internal {
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

**deposit (in another smart contract)**

```
function deposit(address supporter, uint256 tokensAmount) onlyOwner public payable{

    depositedETH[supporter] = depositedETH[supporter].add(msg.value);
    depositedToken[supporter] = depositedToken[supporter].add(tokensAmount);

    emit Deposit(supporter, msg.value, tokensAmount);
}
```

So buyTokens won't work unless I comment out EITHER the deposit call or the forwardFunds call. After doing some reading I was thinking that it had something to do with gas?

Furthermore, if I call the deposit function by passing the value as a param rather than receiving through the msg object in the other function (not using .value() methodology) it works fine.

```
vault.deposit(beneficiary, tokens, msg.value)
```

Is there an issue with using a .value() call and also forwarding to an internal function that uses .transfer()?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! You said  
> "`buyTokens` won't work",
but in which way? Kindly share which message lets you know there is a problem. Like a call with arguments and what you see then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is forwarding the ether sent to the vault contract

```
vault.deposit.value(msg.value)(beneficiary, tokens);
```

And this is forwarding the ether sent to the wallet contract

```
wallet.transfer(msg.value);
```

Obviously you cannot forward the same ether to two different contracts.

Comment: I think you pointed out the issue of it trying to send an amount twice.

So, out of curiosity, if the contract containing the buyTokens function had a bunch of ether itself stored in it, would it be able to execute? Ex: if someone fires the buyTokens function, it fires the deposit function and sends a value (using the ether stored within the contract), AND THEN does THE transfer function, sending the same amount (from itself) to the wallet. Provided the contract had enough ether, would it work? This is just as a thought experiment. Obviously I won't want to do that

Comment: Yes, if the contract has enough funds the second transfer will succeed.